# g++46: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, c++, g++

I'm on FreeBSD 9.2. The `gcc` version is 4.2. My project needs `c++11` so I install `gcc` 4.6 and in Codeblocks I change the build option to support `c++11` and in toolchain section I write `g++46` and `gcc46`.

Now the problem is when I compile my project it has this error:

```
g++46: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```